# Dependence of finite part of loop integral on regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, dimensional-regularization

Recently I've calculated some process in which arise triangle loop with running two $W$ bosons and one massless fermion. The expression for integral is following:
$$
I_{\alpha \beta}(r, q) = \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2 \pi )^{4}}\frac{p_{\alpha}(p_{\beta} + r_{\beta})}{((p - q)^{2} - m_{W}^{2})((p + q)^{2} - m_{W}^{2})(p + r)^{2}}
$$
I need to calculate its finite part. It can be obtained by using regularization,
$$
\tag 1 I_{\alpha \beta}^{finite}(p, q) = I_{\alpha \beta}(r, q) - I_{\alpha \beta}(0, 0),
$$
or through direct calculation,
$$
\tag 2 I_{\alpha \beta}^{finite}(p, q) = \int \frac{d^{4}p}{(2 \pi )^{4}}\left( I_{\alpha \beta}(p, r, q) - I_{\alpha \beta}(p, 0, 0)\right)
$$

Questions.

1. Can I expect that expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ give the same result?
2. If not, which expression, $(1)$ or $(2)$, will give the correct result?

**An edit**
Of course, $(1)$ and $(2)$ haven't give the same result, because they correspond to different recipes of renormalization (different renormalization points). The answer on the second question is undetermined, because it requires details of theory in which $I_{\alpha \beta}$ arises.