# Charge loop corrections

Tags: gauge-theory, charge, renormalization

Let's assume some theory in which there is some gauge group (spontaneously broken) field $B$ and fermion field $b$ which isn't charged under this group, and this statement must hold for each order of perturbation theory. As for beginning, on tree-level there isn't $\bar{b}\gamma^{\mu}B_{\mu}b$ term in lagrangian.

Then let's assume that there is loop-mediated process which involve decay of $B$ boson into 2 $b$'s particles. For contracting the infinity we need to introduce local counterterm $c \bar{b}\gamma^{\mu}B_{\mu}b$ which provides local coupling $b$ to $B$. Coupling constant $c$ isn't determined uniquely: it is fixed up to finite part. From the other side, at tree level $c$ naively somehow corresponds to charge of $b$ fermion under $B$ group. The questions:

1) What to deal with the interpretation of $c$ as physical charge, if it contains infinite part?

2) If the infinite part doesn't contribute to charge (unfortunately I don't understand how), does the condition of absense of charge provide restriction on finite part of $c$? For example, is it possible to fix it like it is fixed in QED?

Answer (score 1):

1) Every "bare charge" contains an infinite part. The reason why we introduce the infinite part is precisely so that the divergences in loop integrals cancel. Physically you never measure bare charges: you always measured a suitably "dressed" charge that is typically scale dependent and is subject to screening effects, etc.

2) The finite part is always fixed by comparison with experiment. You would measure some cross section or decay rate and fit the finite part of the counterterm to match. You can't "fix" the charge in QED: it's a free parameter of the theory.

Now that I believe the conceptual issues are dealt with, let me just point out that the type of diagram you're probably thinking of would not have an infinite part.

[image]

The integrand would look something like

$$ \frac{1}{k^2 - M^2 }\frac{1}{(p + k)^2 - M^2} \frac{1}{\gamma^\mu(p_1 + k)_\mu - m} \underset{\text{large }k}{\approx}  \frac{\gamma^\mu k_\mu}{k^6}$$

So the $d^4k$ measure together with the spinor stuff gives 4 factors of $k$ in the numerator, but there's 6 factors of $k$ in the denominator and the integral is convergent.

Maybe you're thinking of a diagram like this,

[image]

but that diagram requires a term in the Lagrangian of the form $g\phi\phi\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$ which cannot appear in a renormalizable theory because the coupling $g$ would have dimension $[\text{Mass}]^{-1}$.

Maybe there is some example where this is possible but at least with spinors I don't think so. Perhaps it can be done with scalars.

Comment: Theory which I investigate provides diagram $Y \to ee$ (where Y - some vector boson (with mass which arises from spontaneously symmetry breaking) which interacts only with electroweak bosons) which corresponds to amplitude $M$ with loop in which two $W$ bosons and one fermion run,
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173428/ .

Comment: The requirement of absense of charge of electron (which is a property of investigated theory) provides (if I understand correctly) condition $M_{counterterm} + M \sim e\epsilon^{\mu}(p_{X})\gamma_{\mu} = 0$, but I don't understand for which momentums this must hold. For example, in QED physical charge is determined from condition $\Gamma_{\mu} (p_{\gamma} \to 0) = e_{phys}\gamma_{\mu}$, where $\Gamma_{\mu}$ corresponds to renormalized vertex function, while $p_{\gamma}$ corresponds to photon momemtum. Maybe in my theory must be $\Gamma_{\mu} (p_{Y} \to 0) = 0$?